# How do I get gnome to use the same keymap for control as normal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, keyboard-layout

I'm using a relatively new centos system with Gnome. I have set  the keyboard to dvorak, which was really easy and straightforward.

However, for some reason, the control keys are still qwerty. I didn't have this problem with older Gnomes.

ETA: This is only in terminal. emacs works fine.

Comment: What's the setting of Preferences->Keyboard->Layouts->"Separate layout for each window"?

Comment: Possibly related?  [Bug 162726 - Multiple Latin layouts in XKB break keyboard shortcuts](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=162726)

Comment: Define terminal. Unless you mean "terminal emulator under X Windows", there's no way the GNOME keymap settings would be able to affect the *terminal*...

Comment: Hmm, if you are using the GNOME terminal emulator, it would make sense, as this is probably GTK-based and Emacs is not necessarily GTK-based (although it can (or could) be built with the GTK libraries, which are *not* required for the X Windows emacs). If this is the weird behavior @Mikel pointed out, that would explain why Emacs works.

Comment: @Mikel: I'm musing the same layout for all windows, and it uses dvorak for normal typing, just not modified keys.

Comment: @njsg: Yes, I'm using the GNOME terminal emulator. Whatever the xterm equivalent is.