# Wrong keybindings in Dvorak

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout, key-mapping

Using Dvorak as the selected keyboard layout, I find this strange behavior:

The copy+paste keybindings in some programs don't work with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in the dvorak position, but they work in the qwerty position (without changing layouts).

For example in Okular pressing Ctrl+c doesn't do anything, but Ctrl+j works as copy. The "j" in dvorak is in the place of the "c" in qwerty. To paste the copied text in an editor, like Emacs or Libreoffice Writer, I press Ctrl+v in Dvorak (Ctrl+. in qwerty).

In other words, without leaving the dvorak layout, some programs like Okular still see the keyboard in qwerty. How can I solve this problem making all programs work with the actual layout selected?

I'm using Mageia, but I'm pretty sure this happened to me in Fedora.

Comment: Does it depend on which layout is active when you start the application? (Beware that for KDE applications, what matters may be when kdeinit is started.)

Comment: This sounds like https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/23244 and similar bugs.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55919/how-do-i-get-gnome-to-use-the-same-keymap-for-control-as-normal

Comment: @Gilles I dont change active layouts since startup, and the problem persists. Dolphin also sees a qwerty layout for copy+paste+cut.

Comment: And @Mikel, yes, there seems to be many similar reports/bugs. I'm using KDE, and many talk about Gnome, but the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same thing if there are multiple layouts available. Pressing Ctrl will always use the first layout in the list of layouts. Meaning that, if Dvorak is not the first, you will get this behaviour. It could be confusing but I find it useful.

However, the problem is that this does not always apply, depending on the active application. Now I'm looking for a solution where I would get the same behaviour but consistently.

This - https://github.com/tbocek/dvorak - apparently should work with Wayland. Haven't tried it yet but there are reports that it works.